# sudo su to an other user to run script

Tags: linux, security, sudo, sudoers

I am trying to login as USER1 and switch user to USER2 and execute some scripts (100+ scripts, can't list them all out in the sudoer file one by one) as USER2

in the Sudoer file i have

```
   USER1 ALL=(USER2) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

When i run the following as USER1

```
  sudo su - USER2 -c "test.sh"
```

I get

> Sorry, user USER1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - USER2 -c
>   test.sh' as root

if i run

```
  sudo su - sassrv
```

I get

> Sorry, user USER1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - USER2'

If i change the Sudoer file to

```
         USER1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - USER2
```

It will let me switch user, but i am still getting

> Sorry, user USER1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - USER2 -c
>   test.sh' as root

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted to run `test.sh` as USER2 with `sudo`, but instead you run `su` as root.

`su` may in turn try to run `test.sh` as USER2, but that's beyond the scope and knowledge of `sudo`. From `sudo`'s point of view, the only thing you're doing is trying to run a command as root.

Instead, ask `sudo` to run `test.sh` as USER2 directly:

```
sudo -u USER2 test.sh
```

PS: `sudo su` in any context is a code smell that indicates a lack of understanding of what `sudo` is and does.

Comment: `@that other guy` thanks for the quick reply. I can run the script, however, it seems like it is not running as USER2. cos within the test.sh it is writing to a log `echo "test" > test.log`. and it doesn't have permission to create the log.

Comment: If you put `whoami` as the second line in the script (right after the shebang), what does it say?

Comment: `@that other guy` got it. i forgot to specify the directory to write the log to. It was trying to write to `/home/USER1` instead of `/home/USER2`